# setAttr function in Autodesk Maya

Tags: python, maya

I am still learning Python in Maya. I cannot get my code to work. I am trying to create a locator and parent it under my selection and then zero out the locators transforms.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

sel = cmds.ls(selection = True)
loc = cmds.spaceLocator()
cmds.parent(loc, sel)
cmds.setAttr(loc, "translateX", 0)
```

I always get this error message:

```
#Error: TypeError: file <maya console> line 7: Invalid argument 1, '[u'locator6']'. Expected arguments of type ( list, )
```

Sometimes with a bit other code I get something like:

```
#There does not exist something with name 'translateX'
```

I know that it does work when I replace `loc` with the name of the locator, but I try to keep the code as universal as I can and not bound to the name of a locator.

How does the `setAttr` function work in Maya with variables? Maya docs and other questions at various forums could not help... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setAttr` takes one complete attribute as its argument:

```
 cmds.setAtt( loc + ".translateX", 0)
```

where `loc` has to be a single string.  `spaceLocator` like most creation commands returns a list, not a single string.  So the whole thing is:

```
sel = cmds.ls(selection = True)
loc = cmds.spaceLocator()
cmds.parent(loc, sel)
cmds.setAttr(loc[0] + ".translateX", 0)
```

Comment: If it worked, you should mark it as accepted so that other people will know to use it if they have the same question

Comment: Sorry, that not active on this forums.
Marked it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know you seem to be asking asking for maya cmds but I'd like to chime this in as an alternative.

In PyMel the spaceLocator function returns the created object itself. The attributes are then methods inside the object, allowing you to do the following. One reason why I love PyMel!

```
import pymel.core as pm

sel = pm.selected()[0]
loc = pm.spaceLocator()
pm.parent(loc, sel)
loc.translateX.set(0)
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that but Pymel is just another python library (like maya.cmds) that is part of maya. It's up to you which one you prefer but I prefer pymel for various reasons.

Comment: Yeah but I dont want learning more Pymel syntax and some functions only specific for Maya when my actual purpose is to learn Pyhon for several programs

Comment: Your alternative to pymel is maya.cmds which is also just maya specific functions. To be honest learning Pymel makes you a better python programmer than maya.cmds as it teaches you about object oriented programming. Up to you :)